# Algorithm for SigmaJS node positioning

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sigma.js

I'm trying to create a visual graph of points in a readable and not messy way,
I have ids which represents the nodes and contact that represents the child nodes of the parent node.

I have manage to plot them all and connect them correctly based on parent-child relationship but my problem now is to actually position them to look visually okayish.

my code so far is this: (don't mind the value of cx, cy as thats where I'm stuck with)

```
var json_data = JSON.parse('[{"id":1,"contact":[{"id":2,"contact":[{"id":5},{"id":6},{"id":7}]},{"id":3,"contact":[{"id":8},{"id":9},{"id":10}]},{"id":4,"contact":[{"id":11},{"id":12},{"id":13}]}]}]');

var g = {
      nodes: [],
      edges: []
    };

var gx = 0, gy = 0;

processLevel(json_data, gx, gy);

function processLevel(data, cx, cy, parent = null) {

    console.log("Function Called: data length = " +  data.length);

    console.log("cy = " +  cy);

    for(var x = 0; x < data.length; x++){

        console.log(data[x].id);
        cx = x;
        console.log("cx = " +  cx);

        g.nodes.push({
            id: 'n' + data[x].id,
            label: 'Node ' + data[x].id,
            x: cx*cy,
            y: cy,
            size: 1,
            color: '#FF2D00'
        });

        if(parent) {
            g.edges.push({
                id: 'e-' + parent + '-' + data[x].id,
                source: 'n' + parent,
                target: 'n' + data[x].id,
                size: 1,
                color: '#000'
            });
        }

        if(typeof data[x].contact !== 'undefined') {
            cy++;
            processLevel(data[x].contact, cx, cy, data[x].id);
        } 
    }
}



// Instantiate sigma:
s = new sigma({
  graph: g,
  container: 'graph-container'
});
```

desirable output would be something like this:

[image]

Comment: Which version of sigma.js are you using?

Comment: Did you try to use any layout algorithm?

Comment: I'm using the latest sigma version and I havent tried any layout algorithm yet except for the nooverlap plugin @Mehdi

Comment: You may want to try [graphology-layout-forceatlas2](https://github.com/graphology/graphology-layout-forceatlas2), since you are on sigma v2. The examples contains one demo of how this is done.